# CLI Tool to manipulate / compress images in pdf

Tags: pdf, image-manipulation

In a large pdf with high image quality (20 pages, around 400 MB):

For Linux, is there a CLI tool that

- reduces the file size by reducing the quality of all (or single) images within the pdf
- allows me to define the amount of compression applied to the images (e.g. by specifying an absolute target file size or target image size percentage)
- so that, except for the image quality, the overall look of the pdf stays the same?

If not, is there a GUI tool which does this without adding a lot of work?

I browsed through the [List of PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PDF_software) software on Wikipedia, but couldn’t spot the right tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good answer on [*Ask Ubuntu*](https://askubuntu.com/a/256449) explaining how to reduce PDF file size using [*ghostscript*](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/gs.1.html):

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

Quality can be adjusted using `-PDFSETTINGS` option, see the [original answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/256449) for details.